# Настроить перемещение спама во входящие

Tags: email, outlook

Есть почта @live.ru. Хочу чтобы в ней вообще не использовалась фильтрация спама, потому что использую её для всяких акций, регистраций и подписок, а часть сообщений отправляются в спам. Ещё до её перехода на outlook'овскую систему отключал в ней фильтрацию спама, но даже тогда это не работало. Но сейчас ещё больше полезных сообщений отправляются в спам :(

Думал настроить через автоматическое перемещение сообщений из папки Спам во Входящие, но там нужно какой-то фильтр для правила указать - поставить вообще для сего не могу, т. к. часть писем сортируются по папкам. А фильтра типа "находится в папке" я там не вижу.

Как можно такое сделать?